# Django using template tag to determine which objects should appear

Tags: django

.I have a template which display 2  `<div>`  .First  `<div>` shows student questions and the other  `<div>`  shows a form that allow you to edit the questions

[image]

My Model is below . A Student has 5 objects created for them already.What I am trying to figure out is , How can I only show the `<div>` containing the question form if all the questions objects have the field question blank . instead of showing both forms?

Because I don't want to show the list of questions first when their no question . I want to show the question form first . So It would allow them to add their question

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views

```
def DisplayAll(request):
    q = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    form = formset_factory(QuestionForm)
    formset = form(initial=q)
    return render(request,'question.html',{'formset':formset,'question':question})
```

template

This one shows the question

```
 <div>
 {% for question in q %}
 {{question.question}}
 {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

this one shows the form

```
 <div>
      {% for f in formset %}
      {{f}}
      {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want, but I assume that you want to avoid showing the div which contains the question form if there are no questions.

So, in order to do that simply use a `if else` tag to help you do that.

Comment: @Games Brainiac , their only 2 <div> You can see . How can you use if else to filter if all the objects show none , then show this whole <div>

Answer (score 0):

You may want this using [`for ... empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty)

```
<div>
 {% for question in q %}
    {{question.question}}

 {%empty%}
    <div>
      {% for f in formset %}
      {{f}}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

Comment: rohan , the objects are created already . I think the empty only works if their are objects . I just if the field is empty